# Can somebody help me by explaining this

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

```
int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), aTemp => Convert.ToInt32(aTemp));
```

Since this is not a traditional method of putting elements can somebody explain it ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall

Answer (score 1):

This code is reading a line from console, naively expecting the user to insert a bunch of integers separated by space, and populating an array of `int` with these integers.

[`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8) reads a line of text from the user.
[`Split(' ')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) splits a string by space, resulting in an array of strings.
[`ConvertAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netframework-4.8) takes in an array of one type, and returns an array of another type, using a conversion method it takes in as a parameter.
`aTemp => Convert.ToInt32(aTemp)` is that conversion method, as a [lambda expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

I wrote it's "naively expecting the user to..." because you should never trust the user's input. If the user enter a value such as `1 gr 4 6` this code will break with an exception.

Comment: Why do we have to use =>  ? Is it a must or is there like any other "character" we can use ?

Comment: You don't have to. In this case, it could be written as `Convert.ToInt32` converter is a delegate, and if you have a method that it's signature match the delegate, you don't have to use a lambda expression to pass it to the delegate.